# .NET WCF as backend server for iPhone games

Tags: iphone, .net

I'm planning to develop an iPhone game. Is it possible to use .NET WCF as a backend?
The server would be windows 2008 and MS-SQL database.

Comment: I am not sure how mature the Apple SOAP development tools are so you might want to use the WCF REST stuff (`WebHttpBinding`). WCF is pretty slow so if you are thinking of making a realtime multiplayer game with it you **won't** have any success.

Comment: Hi Jon, are WCF rest much faster? thank you for the comment.

Comment: @Jonathan: Could you please provide links supporting the claim that WCF is not good for realtime apps? As far as I know WCF + protobufs can give good performance.

Comment: @Den erm, that's true - question is, do the iPhone tools support the 'proprietary' stuff that they did with that?

Comment: OP: The WCF Rest stuff is **marginally** faster because it doesn't have all the SOAP overhead that Lurca described: but it's definitely not suited to realtime games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAP has a lot of XML overhead! And parsing XML is always slow. Especially on mobile devices. 
Use REST and JSON. There even is something like JSON-RPC, just google for it.